# How to hide the convergence icon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

[image]

How can I hide this icon in Firefox? View -> Toolbars -> Customize doesn't work, because if I restart Firefox, it comes back.

http://convergence.io/

Answer (score 0):

Check for an extension with this name in Tools -> Add-ons manager and disable it (you can also open it by typing **about:addons** in the Location bar).

---

Per comment below, this answer should include information on how to hide the button without disabling the extension. Add this line to [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css&printable=yes) and restart Firefox.

```
#convergence-button {display:none !important;}
```

Please also notify *info@convergence.io* of the problem so they can fix the behavior of the icon re-appearing after restart.

Comment: That disables the add-on completely. They just want to hide the icon.

Comment: I will write to that e-mail BUT PLEASE DON'T WRITE E-MAIL ADDRESSES IN PLAIN TEXT ON A WEBSITE!

Comment: Lance, there is no problem with posting *that* email address.